# Execute Queries Against CMS within SSRS Reports?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssrs

Is it possible to execute queries against a Central Management Server (CMS) using SSRS?

For example, I know of no way to tell a stored procedure that it is inherently supposed to call the CMS, so it would seem some sort of qualifier to indicate that you are querying CMS (and which CMS) would need to be specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using SSRS, but you can use powershell to read from CMS and then use the SQLCMD cmdlet to execute queries.

Comment: Got it, thanks again Jason. I'll make another question about how to do this with Powershell :)