# SSRS - Query CMS and Get Disk Space

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, central-management-server

We're using SQL Server 2019

I have CMS setup and have a query that returns current disk space usage on each registered instance. I can run the query successfully from CMS and get the results I'm looking for.

Unfortunately, when I run the same query in SSRS, it only returns the server information that it is querying from. [I see this same question, but it's from 2012](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13685/execute-queries-against-cms-within-ssrs-reports). Wondering if anything has changed for SQL 2019.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing has changed in this respect. The answer on the question to which you linked is still correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute Queries Against CMS within SSRS Reports?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13685/execute-queries-against-cms-within-ssrs-reports)